# How do you change the size of a size of an angular ui bootstrap date picker popup?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

Here's what I'm referring to:
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

I don't see anything that indicates how to control the size.  I tried changing the body font but that didn't work out

Comment: Did you end up finding a way to enlarge the datepicker?

Answer (score 5):

This size of the datepicker can be changed by overriding the css for the bootstrap form-control and btn classes as shown in the following example:

```
.my-datepicker .form-control {
    height: 10px;
    padding: 11px;
}

.my-datepicker .btn {
    padding: 1px 2px;
}
```

then apply the my-datepicker class to the datepicker input-group

```
<span class="input-group my-datepicker">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="validToDate" is-open="opened1" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
     <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button></span>
</span>
```

Comment: This affects also the size of the input and the size of the button to open the datepicker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZMc1vzonm4VIb6oo3iSn?p=preview