# Cannot resize inline Angular-UI Bootstrap Date-Picker

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I'm using Angular-UI's latest Datepicker control, inline, and I can't figure out how to make it bigger so it takes up the entire page (or its container).

Has anyone attempted/achieved this desired result?

Datepicker control: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/datepicker from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

I tried:

- manually setting width on control,
- played with different parent containers
- was hopeful but no luck on this: [How do you change the size of a size of an angular ui bootstrap date picker popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292918/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-a-size-of-an-angular-ui-bootstrap-date-picker-popu)
- even though its Jquery related, tried [How to resize the jQuery DatePicker control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659588/how-to-resize-the-jquery-datepicker-control)
- changing container/element font-size appears to make no difference

Code:

```
        <div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px!important; min-width:800px!important;">
            <div uib-datepicker ng-model="dt" class="col-12" datepicker-options="options"></div>
        </div>
```

Any information is appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce this in stackblitz.com?

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how I'm supposed to make the control larger.. just increase width/height?